# How to create view with multiple joins on same table

Tags: sql, oracle, view, oracle-apex

In my database I have these two tables:

**Person**

```
+----+---------+---------+
| pk |  name   | sirname |
+----+---------+---------+
|  1 | john    | leno    |
|  2 | william | wallice |
|  3 | eva     | apple   |
|  4 | walter  | white   |
+----+---------+---------+
```

**Request**

```
+----+-------------+----------+---------------+---------+---------+
| pk | requestdate | accepted | requestperson | parent1 | parent2 |
+----+-------------+----------+---------------+---------+---------+
|  1 | 1/1/2014    | Y        |             1 | 2       | 3       |
|  2 | 1/2/2014    | N        |             4 | NULL    | NULL    |
+----+-------------+----------+---------------+---------+---------+
```

To get the requests I do:

```
SELECT * 
FROM request
LEFT JOIN person p_subject ON requestperson = p_subject.pk
LEFT JOIN person p_parent1 ON parent1 = p_parent1.pk
LEFT JOIN person p_parent2 ON parent2 = p_parent2.pk
```

This works perfect but when I want to create a VIEW:

```
CREATE VIEW v_request AS
SELECT * 
FROM request
LEFT JOIN person p_subject ON requestperson = p_subject.pk
LEFT JOIN person p_parent1 ON parent1 = p_parent1.pk
LEFT JOIN person p_parent2 ON parent2 = p_parent2.pk
```

I get this error: `ORA-00957: duplicate column name`

I do not want to rename all columns manually. How can I fix this?

Comment: CREATE VIEW v_request (cname1, cname2, ... ) AS is the easiest way.

Comment: You will definitely have to list the column names somewhere; there's pretty much no getting around that.

Comment: I'm thinking that renaming the columns in the view would have taken less time than writing up the question.... just saying. And why wouldn't you want to rename them? Otherwise how do you reference the values from the correct join? (i.e. which sirname column is the parent surname versus the subject sirname?)

Answer (score 2):

Your view would consist of:

- three columns with the columnname `pk`
- three columns with the columnname `name` (which is not a good columnname)
- three columns with the columnname `sirname`

because the tablealiases will not be prepended automatically (which the error `ORA-00957: duplicate column name` states exactly)

I am quite sure you will have to rename them manually to `subject_pk`, `subject_name`, `subject_sirname` and so on.